# Versioning of Xamarin iOS apps

Tags: ios, git, xamarin, versioning, xamarin-studio

I wanted to know how you deal with the versioning of your iOS apps. `CFBundleShortVersionString` should match with the version submitted to iTunes Connect and `CFBundleVersion` is your unofficial build number.

For `CFBundleShortVersionString` often the format *{MajorVersion}.{MinorVersion}.{Revision}* is used. One could use the *{Build}* number for the `CFBundleVersion`. Another possibility would be to use some sort of revision number from the VCS or in my case the SHA1 hash of the commit of GIT.

If you submit an app to the app store the `CFBundleVersion` is used to determine if your app is an update. It is only allowed to use digits and the dot separator here and it should be higher than the older version. So using a hash doesn't work here and there is no revision number in GIT. Once the app is ready for release the app can use the same value for `CFBundleShortVersionString` and `CFBundleVersion` if you have some different naming for the build number which is not compatible with the app store.

Currently the only thing which comes to my mind is to manually enter the version number if the app is ready for release. So you start counting if you have v. 1.0.0 and increases the number if you provide a new release. If you have a new beta version (e.g. you are planning a new release 2.0.0), what do you use for `CFBundleVersion`? Or what if you use continous integration and a new build is generated each day at midnight?

Also is there an automated process which connects Xamarin Studio, Info.plist and GIT so that for example the build number is increased on each commit? And how does such a process look like?

Bonus question: What information do you show the user in the about dialog of the app?

Answer (score 1):

This is not full answer on how to handle inserting version into Info.plist and iOS versioning but instead how MonoDevelop/XamarinStudio creates version number from GIT commits. Which you can probably use to hack some way to update your Info.plist.

https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/tree/master/scripts
This folder has 3 files .sh and .bat are just to compile third file(.cs) and execute it.
So if you look into this .cs file you will see:

- How to get "git.exe"
- How to run blame on [version.config](https://github.com/mono/monodevelop/blob/master/version.config)(this is file where you manually insert versions like(5.5, 5.7, 5.8...)
- How to run "rev-list --count " + hash + "..HEAD" which means count all commits between last change to version.config file and current commit. So if version.config was changed 143 commits ago, version will be 5.5.0.143, you can of course still use 3rd place for service packs.
- And also some output of this informations like for example buildinfo which can then be used by other parts of build process to insert into Info.plist.

I hope this helps you to solve your problem.